# Push stops coming after a certain number Android GCM

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am currently developing a messaging software where I want to send push notification to users phone via Google Cloud Messaging server at first it works like a charm but after 20 pushes it stops coming. I thought there must be any limit from GCM but there isn't. Cant figure it out why after 20 pushes it stops coming.

What seems to be the problem? Any clue? Any suggestion?

Comment: I have tested with 50 push messages which were sent 10 seconds interval to same device and all of them received by device. But when I sent 50 messages at same time, device was locked down

Comment: Any error codes you're receiving?